# Not able to access to ArangoDB web interface

Tags: laravel, arangodb, arangodb-php

I've installed ArangoDB on an Ubuntu server.
I can connect with arangosh but not able to connect from the web interface.

Tried so many things like in conf files :

`tcp://0.0.0.0:8529`

`tcp://my.server.ipaddress:8529`

`tcp://myservern.ndd:8529`

Always getting : ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the `tcp://`. Its intended if you use [arangosh](https://docs.arangodb.com/Arangosh/) as a client to ArangoDB or via a driver.

If you use your browser, you should use regular `http://` - so in your case:

```
http://my.server.ip.address:8529/
```

or...

```
http://myserver.ndd:8529
```

You should also make sure that no firewall is blocking the connection (e.g. port not open), and revalidate

```
netstat -alnpt
```

that arangod really listens to `0.0.0.0:8529`

Comment: I modified arangod conf file with ip address and also domain name but I am always getting : 2016-05-18T09:12:31Z [22227] FATAL invalid endpoint 'http://X.X.X.X:8529' * database version check failed, you need to run 'upgrade'?

Comment: start arangodb appending the --upgrade parameter to upgrade your schema to your new version; after that you should be able to start regulary.

Comment: Still getting sudo arangodb restart --upgrade
 * Starting arango database server arangod                                            2016-05-18T09:24:14Z [22558] FATAL invalid endpoint '[http://X.X.X.X:8529](http://X.X.X.X:8529)'
 * database version check failed, you need to run 'upgrade'?

Comment: most probably the init scripts accept `sudo arangodb upgrade` to start the arangod with `--upgrade`

Comment: sudo arangodb upgrade
[sudo] password for forge: 
sudo: arangodb: command not found

Comment: Ok it's sudo service arangodb upgrade :
2016-05-18T10:36:50Z [23560] WARNING flock on lockfile '/var/lib/arangodb/LOCK' failed: forbidden
2016-05-18T10:36:50Z [23560] ERROR database is locked, please check the lock file '/var/lib/arangodb/LOCK'
2016-05-18T10:36:50Z [23560] FATAL cannot start server: database directory is locked

Comment: You can only run upgrade if no arangod is currently running with that database. Try `sudo /etc/init.d/arangod stop; sudo /etc/init.d/arangod upgrade; sudo /etc/init.d/arangod start`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112277/discussion-between-adelinemr-and-dothebart).

Answer (score 3):

It was actually because the port 8529 was not opened so I opened it with :

```
sudo ufw allow 8529
```

And don't forget to add your domain instead of localhost IP on arangod.conf :

```
endpoint = tcp://your.dev.ndd:8529
```